# <h:selectOneRadio> dynamic Value to Backing Bean

Tags: jsf-2

I have written a piece of code to put two pairs of radio button in a *.xhtml page of a JSF project built in JSF2.0, Jboss As 7.1.1 final and JDK 6.0, PrimeFaces 3.4.2.

```
           <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:selectOneRadio value="#{calendarBean.radioFirst}">
                    <f:selectItem id="morning" itemValue="morning" itemLabel="Morning"/>
                    <f:selectItem id="afternoon" itemValue="afternoon" itemLabel="Afternoon"/>
                </h:selectOneRadio>
                <h:selectOneRadio style="padding-left: 170px" value="#{calendarBean.radioSecond}">
                    <f:selectItem id="noon" itemValue="noon" itemLabel="Noon"/>
                    <f:selectItem id="endofday" itemValue="endofday" itemLabel="End Of Day"/>
                </h:selectOneRadio>
            </h:panelGrid>
```

The Bean is:

```
private String radioFirst="morning";
private String radioSecond="endofday";

public String getRadioFirst() {
    return radioFirst;
}

public void setRadioFirst(String radioFirst) {
    this.radioFirst = radioFirst;
}

public String getRadioSecond() {
    return radioSecond;
}

public void setRadioSecond(String radioSecond) {
    this.radioSecond = radioSecond;
}
```

I have written a method to invoke on a Action Event where I want to have the values of the radio button selected. when the method invokes I get the value of the radio buttons as "morning" and "endofday" as these two are the initial values of the bean variables.

```
private String radioFirst="morning";
private String radioSecond="endofday";
```

But if I change the radio button options, I don't get the updated values, its the same old initial values. How can I get the changed values? Please help!

Comment: did you put `<h:panelGrid />` in a `<h:form />` tag?

Comment: What is the bean scope definition? Where is your action `commandButton`? Have you included a `h:form`?

Comment: Bean scope is `@SessionScoped` and action commandButton is `<p:commandButton actionListener="#{userLeaveBean.addAppliedLeave}" styleClass="apply_button" value="Create Leave" onclick="window.reload()">
     <f:attribute name="userId" value="#{employee.name}"/>
     <f:attribute name="firstHalf" value="#{calendarBean.radioFirst}"/>
     <f:attribute name="secondHalf" value="#{calendarBean.radioSecond}"/>
    </p:commandButton>`. The code is within the `<h:form>`tag

Comment: You are getting values back with `event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("firstHalf")` ... ?

Comment: Yes, it gives back the value,but not the changed ones, only the defaults.

Comment: That is the problem, your `f:attribute` are set at the page generation time so initialized to default value and keep that when the `p:commandButton` is clicked.

Comment: How can I get the radio button Values then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things

1. Don't use the session scope for this usage scenario. This will go completely wrong when your users open the same page in more than one tab. Use request scope or view scope.
2. Use a regular action instead of an action listener, and don't provide the radio button values as attributes. This makes no sense. The selectOneRadio components will set the updated values on your backing bean. When your action method is invoked, you will have access to those values via the instance fields of your bean.
3. Leave out the window.reload. If you need a full page refresh after the action, set ajax to false on the p:commandButton or use an h:commandButton.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your action button like this :

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{userLeaveBean.addAppliedLeave}" styleClass="apply_button" value="Create Leave">
    <f:attribute name="userId" value="#{employee.name}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

As @MikeBraun suggested, remove the `window.reload()`. If you want to refresh something, you could do it by using the `update` attribute from the `p:commandButton`.

And modify your bean according to this :

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped // Could probably be moved to @RequestScoped or @ViewScoped
public class UserLeaveBean
{
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{calendarBean}")
    CalendarBean calendarBean;

    public void setCalendarBean(CalendarBean calendarBean)
    {
        this.calendarBean = calendarBean;
    }

    public void addAppliedLeave(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("Radio 1 : " + calendarBean.getRadioFirst());
        System.out.println("Radio 2 : " + calendarBean.getRadioSecond());
    }
}
```

The `ManagedProperty` will get the other bean accessible for you by injecting it inside the current one. Use the proper scope, probably you are using `SessionScoped` because you are using `window.reload()`.

**Important :** the `ManagedProperty` bean must be at least scoped the same length as the other bean.

**Read more :**

- [Injecting Managed Beans in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/)
- [PrimeFaces Showcase - commandButton](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/commandButton.jsf)

Comment: Injecting Managed Bean thing is very useful, but the modification does not work. :(

Comment: @NGH What is the scope of `CalendarBean` ?

Comment: CalendarBean in @SessionScoped

Comment: @NGH I've added a missing function inside the bean, this should work now (sorry first time I use injection :))

Comment: Its a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: for `System.out.println("Radio 1 : " + calendarBean.getRadioFirst());
        System.out.println("Radio 2 : " + calendarBean.getRadioSecond());`

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the code updated is tested and working. If your beans are sill both `@SessionScoped` or `@ViewScoped` and your application is cleaned/rebuilt/redeployed I don't have clue.

Comment: No I did it in a different way!